# What is the largest number of squares that can be cut by the sides of the triangle in this picture?

Tags: geometry

I came across a question in the Mathematics Olympiad exercise booklet for primary school students in Australia. The questions is presented in the following picture. I can't quite understand what the question is about. Would anyone please help make the question clearer and suggest a solution? Thank you very much in advance.
[image]

Comment: Your task is to set the points B and C on the top and right-hand boundary to form a triangle. This triangle now intersect some of the 30 small squares. Your task is to optimally choose B and C, such that the number of intersected squares is as high as possible.

Comment: By cut I think they mean one of side of the triangle intersect the side of the square at two distinct points

Comment: Thank you, @Nurator, for your clarification of the question. I'm now clear about what I need to do.

Comment: Thank you, @Divide1918, for your clue. I can start from there to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep vertex $A$ at the lower left corner of the grid, and you allow one vertex of the triangle to be anywhere on the right side of the rectangle enclosing the grid, and the other vertex to be anywhere on the top of the rectangle enclosing the grid, what is the maximum possible number of squares that the edges of the triangle will pass through?  You can see in the example figure that the triangle's bottom edge passes through $6$ squares; the top edge passes through another $6$ squares; and the left edge passes through $6$ squares.  But for the bottom and top vertices, the squares are counted twice, so this triangle passes through $6 + 6 + 6 - 2 = 16$ different squares.  By changing the position of the top and right vertices of the triangle, can you make it pass through more squares?

Comment: Thank you, @heropup, for your detailed and informative interpretation of the problem. I will try to work out the problem according to the explanation provided by helpful people like you, Nurator and Divide1918.

Comment: @MichaelMay  Hi Michael,  did you figure out what's the solution for this problem?  Thanks!